# Why do some vaccines lose their efficacy with time?

Tags: bacteriology, virology, vaccination, infection, infectious-diseases

Why do some vaccines lose with time their efficacy?

The two obvious examples that I have in mind are influenza and tetanus. The former case is clear, as influenza virus undergoes frequent gene reshuffling with similar viruses, which renders the vaccine inefficient against what can be essentially considered a new virus. So the question is about tetanus: does it have to do with the fact that it is bacterial rather than a viral effection? Why the immunity is lost? Are there other similar cases?

Comment: @user1136 [Here's a study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4826453/) indicating "antibody responses to tetanus declined with an estimated half-life of 14 years (95% confidence interval, 11-17 years)."

Comment: @user1136 indeed, I presumed the need for "booster" is because of the declining vaccine efficacy (even if it remains quite high). If you have some experise on this subject, please share with us in an answer.